# Looking for clarification on netstat results

Tags: linux, netstat

I am looking for some clarification on the following netstat results. The following results are showing 3 java processes. Is there a way to find which java programs are they referring to?

Another clarification I am looking for is, I have completed disabled tcp6 in my machine. However, the netstat results still show tcp6 in the output. Why so?

```
# netstat -tulpn
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7605/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      820/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2020/master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8443            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7605/java
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9990            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7605/java
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      823/httpd
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      820/sshd
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      2020/master
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:34754           0.0.0.0:*                           623/dhclient
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           623/dhclient
udp6       0      0 :::31623                :::*                                623/dhclient
```

Comment: That seems to be a single process (PID 7605) that is listening on 3 ports (HTTP + HTTPS + ??) - you might get more information by searching the PID e.g. `ps -fp 7605`

Comment: @steeldriver, certain services are listening in the loopback address `127.0.0.1:8080` and certain things looks like this `0.0.0.0:8080`, is there any difference between this two ?

Comment: `0.0.0.0:8080` will accept connections on the machine's external network interfaces, whereas `127.0.0.1:8080` would only accept loopback (internal) connections

Answer (score 1):

Use `--protocol` flag for filter by tcp4.

`netstat --protocol inet -4` will show you only ipv4 sockets.

As for Java processes you have PIDS in netstat output. Use it by `ps` command find your Java programs.

Comment: My question was not about filtering ipv4 sockets. As i have disabled ipv6 in my machine, why am I seeing ipv4 sockets in the result?

Answer (score 1):

The listening on ipv6 sockets are built into those processes.  That is the characteristic of those processes itself and I think can't be disabled unless you compile those applications with the relevant ipv6 configuration.